# How to combine two tables, one with 1 row and one with n rows?

Tags: sql

I have a database with two tables

One with games
and one with participants
A game is able to have more participants and these are in a different table.

Is there a way to combine these two into one query?

Thanks

Comment: Yes of course, but without the details (tables/columns) we can't write it for you.

Comment: What are the columns in the three tables, and what is your expected output?  Example data might help, along with the database you're using...

Comment: What version of SQL are you using (ie. MySQL, SQL Server) and how are the tables formatted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine them using the [JOIN](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1667) operator.

Something like

```
SELECT *
FROM   games g
       INNER JOIN participants p ON p.gameid = g.gameid
```

Explanation on JOIN operators

> INNER JOIN - Match rows between the two tables specified in the INNER
>   JOIN statement based on one or more
>   columns having matching data. 
>   Preferably the join is based on
>   referential integrity enforcing the
>   relationship between the tables to
>   ensure data integrity.
>             o Just to add a little commentary to the basic definitions
>   above, in general the INNER JOIN
>   option is considered to be the most
>   common join needed in applications
>   and/or queries.  Although that is the
>   case in some environments, it is
>   really dependent on the database
>   design, referential integrity and data
>   needed for the application.  As such,
>   please take the time to understand the
>   data being requested then select the
>   proper join option.
>             o Although most join logic is based on matching values between
>   the two columns specified, it is
>   possible to also include logic using
>   greater than, less than, not equals,
>   etc.
>
> LEFT OUTER JOIN - Based on the two tables specified in the join
>   clause, all data is returned from the
>   left table.  On the right table, the
>   matching data is returned in addition
>   to NULL values where a record exists
>   in the left table, but not in the
>   right table.
>             o Another item to keep in mind is that the LEFT and RIGHT OUTER
>   JOIN logic is opposite of one another.
>   So you can change either the order of
>   the tables in the specific join
>   statement or change the JOIN from left
>   to right or vice versa and get the
>   same results.
>
> RIGHT OUTER JOIN - Based on the two tables specified in the join
>   clause, all data is returned from the
>   right table.  On the left table, the
>   matching data is returned in addition
>   to NULL values where a record exists
>   in the right table but not in the left
>   table.
>
> Self -Join - In this circumstance, the same table is
>   specified twice with two different
>   aliases in order to match the data
>   within the same table.
>
> CROSS JOIN - Based on the two tables specified in the join clause, a
>   Cartesian product is created if a
>   WHERE clause does filter the rows. 
>   The size of the Cartesian product is
>   based on multiplying the number of
>   rows from the left table by the number
>   of rows in the right table.  Please
>   heed caution when using a CROSS JOIN.
>
> FULL JOIN - Based on the two tables specified in the join clause,
>   all data is returned from both tables
>   regardless of matching data.

Comment: Right answer, but the definitions are a bit wordy. You might want to add simple summaries, and mention that inner-join is probably the most common join type.

Answer (score 1):

example

table Game has columns (gameName, gameID)
table Participant has columns (participantID, participantName, gameID)

the GameID column is the "link" between the 2 tables. you need a common column you can join between 2 tables.

```
SELECT gameName, participantName
FROM Game g
JOIN Participat p ON g.gameID = p.gameID
```

This will return a data set of all games and the participants for those games. 
The list of games will be redundant unless you structure it some other way due to multiple participants to that game.

sample data

```
WOW        Bob
WOW        Jake
StarCraft2 Neal
Warcraft3  James
Warcraft3  Rich
Diablo     Chris
```